# processing a headered CSV file with gnu parallel

Tags: shell, csv, parallel-processing, gnu

Is it possible to invoke gnu parallel in a way that it would repeat the first line of original input to the STDIN of each child job?

I have a CSV file that contains a header line at the top. For example:

```
> cat large.csv
id,count
abc,123
def,456
```

I have a tool that can extract columns by name rather than position:

```
> csv_extract large.csv count
123
456
```

I can sum the values serially as:

```
> csv_extract large.csv count | awk '{ SUM += $1 } END { print SUM }'
579
```

The actual file I have is much larger, and the operation more complex than summing, but the same principles would apply. I'd like to use gnu parallel to process the file, but I don't know if it is possible to tell gnu parallel to repeat the CSV header for each job.

Ideally I could run the operation with something like:

```
> cat large.csv | parallel --pipe --repeat-first-line "csv_extract /dev/stdin count | awk '{ SUM += $1 } END { print SUM }'"
579
```

I've made up the **--repeat-first-line** option above to represent the functionality I cannot figure out. I've watched the YouTube videos, and read the man page, but I'm just not able to see how it can be done, if at all possible.

Thanks!

- danboo

Comment: could you make a separate run of `parallel` that just adds the header to all files when processing is done? Or actually a `for` loop, if you control where and what names are used for your `parallel` output files. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Today you can `--skip-first-line` and add the header using `echo`:

```
seq 10 | parallel --skip-first-line --pipe '(echo hea,der; cat) | my_prog'
```

In a future version you will have the option '--header' which will be a regexp that matches the end of your header (e.g: '\n' for one line or '\n.*\n' for two lines or '---' for up to and including the first ---)

-- Edit --

Newest version of GNU Parallel can now do:

```
parallel --pipe --header : my_program
```

Comment: I look forward to the `--header` option. And thanks for the `echo` idea. Though it isn't general enough for my use, I can at least use something similar for disk files: `cat large.csv | parallel --skip-first-line --pipe '(head -1 large.csv; cat) | my_prog'`